# Issue with adding months in R for February

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I'm trying to automate the date side of my R script when I noticed this issue.

**When I try to get a date sequence that falls into the month of Feb, there is an issue, it rolls into the next month.**

```
> library(timeDate)
> library(lubridate)
> 
> x <- as.POSIXct("2015-12-31")
> 
> seq(x, by = "month", length.out = 6)
[1] "2015-12-31 EST" "2016-01-31 EST" "2016-03-02 EST" "2016-03-31 EST" "2016-05-01 EST" "2016-05-31 EST"
```

As you can see instead of Feb'16, we have two Mar'16.

Any ideas? or workaround?

Comment: Modified the question now, thanks for pointing initial question as duplicate

Comment: (1) Please don't make your question a moving target. (2) Please read the manual for the function described in the link (`help("%m+%")`). The _second example_ shows that you can add a vector of values (`%m+% months(1:3)`.